# How to not lose an array field text on PHP form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an array input in a form. I want to validate the form using php and not loosing the input if any error occurs. I read previous questions and used the following codes:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['name']))?$_POST['name']:'';?>">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['name']))?$_POST['name']:'';?>">
```

As you see the input is an array.

The problem is when an error occurs, the inputs become **Array** not the previous text in the field.
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input is an array, so is `$_POST['name']`, so you need to index into it to get the name, using indexes *in the same order as the inputs in your file*:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['name'][0]))?$_POST['name'][0]:'';?>">
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['name'][1]))?$_POST['name'][1]:'';?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

When you used `echo $_POST['name']` while `$_POST['name']` is an array, you will echo "Array". You should echo each element in this array

```
<?php

if (is_array($_POST['name'])){
    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name){
        echo '<input type="text" name="name[]" value="' . htmlspecialchars($name) . '"\n"; 
    }
}
```

Also make it a habit to escape untrusted values with `htmlspecialchars` if you are going to inject them into the HTML, to protect against XSS attacks.